# django: how to display image in html_email

Tags: django

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html  >
<head>

<title>Email</title>

</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
     <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" title="" style="height: 6.1rem;">School Collebes
<br><br>
<p>To: {{ email }}</p>

<p>Your Registration has been approved.
Please use this {{ email }} as your username and {{ password }} as your password.
You may now start enrolling your student using this link https://....</p>
<br><br><br>

<h2>REGISTRAR</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my admin.py

```
@admin.register(ParentsProfile)
class ParentsProfile(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Father_Email','Fathers_Firstname' , 'Fathers_Middle_Initial', 'Fathers_Lastname', 'Request')
    ordering = ('Request',)
    search_fields = ('Request',)
    actions = ['Send_Email','Send_Email_Disapproved']
    def Send_Email(self, request, queryset):

        for profile in queryset:
            context = {
                  'email': profile.Father_Email, 
                  'password': profile.Parent_Password, 
            }
            html_message = render_to_string('Homepage/email.html',context=context)
            send_mail(subject="Invite", message='',html_message=html_message, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                       recipient_list=[profile.Father_Email])
```

i just want to display what i desire image in my email_html, but i dont know the reason why i cant display an image. did i something wrong with my code? im pretty sure that the image i declare in my email_html are in correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the image source path. when an email is sent the image source url is relative so it will through 404 for image. Replace the url with complete path 
change the following to

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" title="" style="height: 6.1rem;">
```

change to

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/static/imagepath/logo.png" title="" style="height: 6.1rem;">
```